# How to Improve TEXT_DETECTION of Google Vision API for non-language-specific text such as registration plates

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I rely on [Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr) `textAnnotations` to recognise Italian registration plates.

Problem is *ALL* G's are reported as C's making it completely useless given user has to check one by one which is more error-prone that just hand-typing each plate.

How to get C and G properly recognised? Italian government is quite good in finding the right one when you go over speed limits so I guess the font is not the problem...

E.g. here I get `EY454WC`, `DN862CC`, `DM843CW`, no exception.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [OpenALPR API](https://www.openalpr.com/cloud-api.html) which offers a free plan up.to 1.000 calls per month.

It really does the job!

Comment: free tier is now at 50/month
https://www.openalpr.com/software/carcheck